# Prevent Vim from starting line with pound sign "#"?

Tags: vim, vi

I like to create a lot of text (.txt) files using Vim that contain instructions on how to do things.  For example,

```
# Check Nginx status
sudo service nginx status
```

However, when I write these lines with Vim, when I hit return after typing in a comment line, one that starts with a "#" sign, Vim automatically inserts a "#" sign at the start of the next line and I'll have to backspace twice to get rid of it.

```
# Check Nginx status <return>
#
```

Is there some setting that will prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for 'formatoptions'. The short answer is to do

```
set formatoptions-=r
set formatoptions-=o
```

somewhere in your vimrc. To look at what format options do go `:h fo-table`.
Here is more info http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion

Comment: Thanks MW!  Vim sure is deep.